# Why isn't Ultrasurf hiding my IP address?

Tags: internet, ip, ip-address, blocking, bypass

HELP! This is the first time that happened to me, neither Ultrasurf nor Psiphon3 nor Freegate are hiding my IP. Now, I live in Egypt and my ISP is  TE-DATA, my IP is 41.235.184.188. And as u can see in the picture:
[my ip and ultrasurf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4y7y.png)
 it is the same with Ultrasurf on, but I have noticed something, the country is different ( but that doesnt matter as I still cannot bypass my ISP filters). Help you guys Im literally going insane..

Comment: disabled webrtc via browser extension but still ip leaks, only when using chrome though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to install the [ultrasurf VPN chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultrasurf-security-privac/mjnbclmflcpookeapghfhapeffmpodij?hl=en).

Install it and connect it, and see of the ip changed or not...